# Get other query columns with Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm trying to implement a register/login system in my Android application by using the Parse SDK.

So far, I've made the register & login possible.

What I'm looking for is displaying other user credentials on another activity (e.g. first_name or last_name).

This is my code:

**LoginActivity.java**

```
//Read user information as String.
String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

//Find user by Email and Password.
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Users");

query.whereEqualTo("email", email);
query.whereEqualTo("password", password);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(List<ParseObject> users, ParseException e) {

    if (e == null) {
       //User logged in successful.
       Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Welcome back!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       //Take user to FeedActivity.
       startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, FeedActivity.class));
    } else {
       //User login failed.
       Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
});
```

**RegisterActivity.java**

```
            //Store user information in String.
            String firstname = etFirstname.getText().toString();
            String lastname = etLastname.getText().toString();
            String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            int userID = count.getAndIncrement();

            ParseObject Users = new ParseObject("Users");
            Users.put("userID", userID);
            Users.put("first_name", firstname);
            Users.put("last_name", lastname);
            Users.put("email", email);
            Users.put("password", password);
            Users.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        //User registered successfully.
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration successful."
                                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Take user to LoginActivity.
                        startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration failed."
                                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check sending data through `Intent`'s.

So in first activity You do that:

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("label", "My name, yo!");
startActivity(i);
```

and in second activity:

```
Intent d = getIntent();
String s = d.getStringExtra("label");
```

Or You might go with that: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Building-Data-driven-Apps-with-Parse#passing-objects-between-activities

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right you want something like:

```
if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        String user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
        query.whereEqualTo("objectId",user);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (final ParseObject post : objects) {
                        // Put Data in TextBoxes
                        // String first_name = post.getString("first_name"); - Will return first Name
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    } else {
        //Log in the User
    }
```